Different results in scene/render/exported image, material with combination of emmision and transparent
I've tried everything I know, but still have this issue:
I made a texture with combined emission and transparent shader through noise texture

And if I render it it will look just okay, as I want

But when I export to png with transparent background, it just loose all the color, and details, etc



Please edit your question and add your images directly into it using the built-in tools rather than just posting links to them. This will ensure that they remain visible for future users reading your question. Thanks.

How do your Compositing nodes look? It could be that you disconnected the Alpha output there when compositing for something unrelated.

I don`t have compositing nodes at all, I have alpha channel, but I lost color
